# Does a Noble's wealth pay out when multiclassing?

Tags: star-wars-saga-edition

The Noble's talent *Wealth* adds credits to the character each time a level is gained. It seems unclear whether this is Noble levels, or any levels. Does any general rule in the game shed further light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact quote from the book is:

> Each time you gain a level, (including the level at which you gain this talent), you receive an amount of credits equal to 5,000 * your **noble level**.

I added emphasis to that last part, because the rule is *explicitly* calling out the difference between "a level" and "noble level". So it seems reasonably clear that you get money for any level you gain, but you only increase the amount of money you get by gaining levels in the Noble class.

Comment: that's quite a reasonable observation actually.